# Sound Sensor that can give feedback on the amplitude of different frequencies?

Tags: arduino, sensor, sound

I'm trying to find a sound sensor that can give feedback on all the frequencies of sound and their levels.

The sensors I'm finding in my search however only support level of sound it seems.

Is it possible to get the level of individual frequency ranges from one sensor, or does it require multiple senors?

I'm new to this so don't know the exact terminology, but essentially I want to create something that can respond to a set of different frequencies of sound independently, not just how loud the sound is.

Ideally the sensor would be made to work with Arduino, but I'm not afraid of something that it is more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to perform [an FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) on the microphone input. [FFT software](http://technology911.com/v/sr0ewZHu9jg,arduino-realtime-fft) is available for the Arduino.

Comment: This seems to have more information available and is closer to what I'm trying to do. Found this and it's extremely similar to what I'm trying to do: http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/10/circuit-skills-led-color-organ-spon.html

Answer (score 2):

Would a graphic equalizer sensor do the job you're trying to do?  Sparkfun stocks the [MSGEQ](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10024), a 7-band filter IC which contains integrated bandpass filters and peak detection.   You'll need to connect one pin of your Arduino to its strobe pin, and an ADC pin to read the amplitude.

The bandpass filter and peak detect are, I believe, the building blocks of your desired sensor.

If you want more customization than that, you're probably looking at doing some DSP work on the Arduino-is there a library for that yet?

Comment: Yes! That looks like what I need. What audio input component would you recommend for this?

Comment: Note that the IC combines all the outputs into a single pin.  Looks like you have to hit it with a clock signal to get a DC value for each band?  Then you'd feed that DC value into your arduino ADCs?  Kinda convoluted for something you can just do for free inside the Arduino with an FFT.

Comment: I disagree.  Toggling a pin and taking an ADC reading is MUCH easier than doing an FFT.

Comment: Also this is limited to 7 bands, and it's a peak reading instead of an RMS reading.  An FFT can do as many bands as you want, in whatever way you want.